# Meteor Method to send a public MongoDB document without publishing everything

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

new to meteor and mongo.

I have some JSON stored in mongo that I want to publicly expose via an obfuscated token without using something like:

```
//app/models/stuff.js
Stuff = new Mongo.Collection("stuff");
Meteor.publish("stuff", function (){
    return Stuff.find();
});
//additionally, the client-side subscription
```

I only want to expose the files that the client directly requests via a URL routing parameter or some sort of client side identifier (like a textfield where you can type the code/token in)

e.g., http://website.com/view/abcdefghijklmnop

Anyone with knowledge of the link can type it in, and get the file. However, there should be no way to just get **every** file without being given every token.

I was wondering if this was the best way to accomplish the task:

```
//app/server/stuff.js
Meteor.methods({
    getStuff: getStuff
});

function getStuff(stuffId) {
    var result = Stuff.find({_id: stuffId});
    return result;
}
```

then

```
//app/client/stuff.js
var json = Meteor.call('getStuff', 'abcdefghijklmnop');
```

Comment: sounds like it might be better to use server-side routing for that. Then you can avoid the method call and use the url even from a non-browser (e.g., wget or curl).

Comment: It seems like [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) might be appropriate here.

Comment: hrm, i dont actually want to serve a file, i just want to serve some json to the client. i will update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just publish the requested document?

```js
Meteor.publish('stuff', function (id){
  check(id, String);
  return Stuff.find(id);
});
```

Comment: This was what i had in mind originally, i guess i didn't understand that this was possible. The only examples i saw had the publish selector using the UserID which is not good for me. I guess i glazed over the Meteor.subscription document (which clearly details how to provide arguments), and just read the docs on the publish side. I think this is the obvious way to go.

Comment: Yeah, you can think of methods and publish functions as authorization gatekeepers. They can perform arbitrarily complex checks and return appropriately filtered results.